# r replace character values in a column with the lowest numeric value of that column

Tags: r

I have a data frame where some of the values in some of the columns are entered as 'L' (for too low to measure), and the rest of the values are numeric. I'd like to replace the 'Low' with the lowest numeric value within the column:

What I have:

```
A   4   6   5   L
B   4   L   9   3
C   6   7   6   5
D   L   8   L   3
```

What I'd like:

```
A   4   6   5   3
B   4   6   9   3
C   6   7   6   5
D   4   8   5   3
```

I've gone down a complicated road, generating a look-up table, and then trying to apply that over all the columns in the data frame and I keep thinking there's got to be an easier way.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the columns are `character` class, loop through the columns except the first one, and `replace` the "L" values with `min` of the `numeric` elements and then convert it to `numeric` class.

```
df1[-1] <-  lapply(df1[-1], function(x) as.numeric(replace(x, 
                         x=="L", min(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE))))
df1
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  A  4  6  5  3
#2  B  4  6  9  3
#3  C  6  7  6  5
#4  D  4  8  5  3
```

BTW, using `lapply` is recommended over `apply` as the latter converts to `matrix`.

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
      mutate_each(funs(replace(., .=="L", min(.))), 2:5)
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  A  4  6  5  3
#2  B  4  6  9  3
#3  C  6  7  6  5
#4  D  4  8  5  3
```

---

Or using `set` from `data.table` which is very efficient

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
for(j in 2:ncol(df1)){
 set(df1, i = which(df1[[j]]=="L"), j=j, value = min(df1[[j]]))
 }
df1
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1:  A  4  6  5  3
#2:  B  4  6  9  3
#3:  C  6  7  6  5
#4:  D  4  8  5  3
```

Comment: Thank you! The first solution worked great. There are values in my 'real' data that I neglected to put in my example that complicated the issue- such as NAs and 3 and 10 in the same column selects 10 if evaluating as a character. Your code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

We can `apply` columnwise to get the minimum in the column and replace it wherever you find `"L"`

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x == "L", min(x), x))

#     V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 
#[1,] "A" "4" "6" "5" "3"
#[2,] "B" "4" "6" "9" "3"
#[3,] "C" "6" "7" "6" "5"
#[4,] "D" "4" "8" "5" "3"
```

This would return a `matrix` to get it as data frame

```
data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x == "L", min(x), x)))

#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  A  4  6  5  3
#2  B  4  6  9  3
#3  C  6  7  6  5
#4  D  4  8  5  3
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `dplyr` package, assuming the data frame is called `dat` and the column names are `V1` through `V5`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate_at(vars(V2:V5), funs(replace(., .=="L", min(.))))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  A  4  6  5  3
2  B  4  6  9  3
3  C  6  7  6  5
4  D  4  8  5  3
```